# Сделать, чтобы ListBox вышел вниз за пределы родителя

Tags: html, css

Сделал живой поиск по сайту, при наборе слова внизу появляется список с вариантами совпадений. Код работает, поиск идет.

А вот расположить это всё на странице не получается. Вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот код страницы полностью, стили сюда же воткнул:

```css
.menu {
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #0A7676;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 20px 130px -41px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 20px 130px -41px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 130px -41px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu ul li {
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 55px -10px rgba(142, 30, 194, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 55px -10px rgba(142, 30, 194, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 55px -10px rgba(142, 30, 194, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="search-input"><input id="search" name="search" placeholder="поиск по сайту" type="text"></li>
      <div id="search-result">
        <div class="search-inner">
          <!-- список вариантов -->
          <li><a href="#">Res1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Res2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Res3</a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
      <li><a href="#">Кошки</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Собаки</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Депутаты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Мыши</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  страница сайта
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте для этого позиционирование (свойство `position`).

P.S. теги `li` нужно оборачивать в `ul` так как они часть списка, точно так же как в `ul` не стоит вкладывать `div`

```css
.menu {
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #0A7676;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 20px 130px -41px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 20px 130px -41px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 130px -41px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu ul li {
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 55px -10px rgba(142, 30, 194, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 55px -10px rgba(142, 30, 194, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 55px -10px rgba(142, 30, 194, 1);
}


.c-search {
  position: relative;
}
.c-search__result {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-start !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="search-input">
        <div class="c-search">
          <input class="c-search__field" id="search" name="search" placeholder="поиск по сайту" type="text">
          <ul class="c-search__result" id="search-result">
            <!-- список вариантов -->
            <li><a href="#">Res1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Res2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Res3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Кошки</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Собаки</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Депутаты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Мыши</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  страница сайта
</div>
```